Why the code raise an error rather than destroy the entity in ursina?
I am using ursina to make an endless runner and I got an error at these 3 lines of codes.
def update(self):
    if self.y >= 8:
        destroy(self)

I have tried to ask my friend but kinda no progress. What I expected to happen is the enemy will be destroyed at the end, not to raise an error.

"got an error" – what error do you get? Where do you get destroy() from?

destroy is from the ursina package.

Assertion failed: !is_empty() at line 1044 of panda/src/pgraph/nodePath.cxx
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\ursina\main.py", line 181, in _update    e.update()
File "c:\Users\MyPC\Documents\Stuff\main2.py", line 25, in update
self.y -= 0.08
^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\ursina\entity.py", line 497, in y_getter
return self.getY()
^^^^^^^^^^^

AssertionError: !is_empty() at line 1044 of panda/src/pgraph/nodePath.cxx
:task(error): Exception occurred in PythonTask update
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\MyPC\Documents\Stuff\main2.py", line 35, in 
app.run()
File "C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\ursina\main.py", line 321, in run
super().run()

File "C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\direct\showbase\ShowBase.py", line 3331, in run
self.taskMgr.run()
File "C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\direct\task\Task.py", line 553, in run
self.step()

File "C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\direct\task\Task.py", line 504, in step
self.mgr.poll()
File "C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\ursina\main.py", line 181, in _update    e.update()
File "c:\Users\MyPC\Documents\Stuff\main2.py", line 25, in update
self.y -= 0.08
^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\ursina\entity.py", line 497, in y_getter
return self.getY()
^^^^^^^^^^^

AssertionError: !is_empty() at line 1044 of panda/src/pgraph/nodePath.cxx

Please edit the error message into your question, it's nearly impossible to read from comments.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This error (Assertion failed: !is_empty()) happend when you are trying to destroy an object that does not exist. I think ursina don't know that "self is an entity".

This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question. Once you have enough reputation, you can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question. - From Review
